How can we use Copilot Plugin to retrieve documents based on their metadata or tagging?
How can we use Copilot M365 Plugins to retrieve documents based on their metadata or tagging or formatting?
I want to get Copilot M365's search results so that documents with certain metadata or taggings are high ranking in search results.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
